# Unexpected behaviour of AWS ASG, AWS Launch Template within AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I've created `AWS EKS` cluster, with managed node group(s), as well I've created an `AWS ASG (Auto Scaling Group)` and `AWS Launch Template`. But when I'm attaching an `AWS Launch Template` to managed EKS node groups, it is creating a duplicate of existing (created) `AWS Launch Template`

--

[image: MANAGED AWS EC2 LT]

Those Launch Templates:

**DEV/MANAGED/EKS-WORKERS-SM/LATEST/TEMPLATE/EU-CENTRAL-1X**

and

**eks-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX**

are identical, and I don't understand why EKS is creating for duplicates

--

As well same stuff is happening with `AWS ASG (Auto Scaling Group)`, is there any way to fix this problem?

Technologies which used:

- Terraform

  - Launch Template resource
  - Auto Scaling Group resource
  - EKS resource
  - EKS node group resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you're running both resources. When you want to manage the Nodes only by your self, you don't need to have `EKS node group resource`, instead you need to use `Launch Template resource` with `Auto Scaling Group resource`, and with proper tagging