# Terraform launch template creating two volumes for AWS EKS Cluster Autoscaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have a EKS Cluster with a Node Group that is configured with launch template. All of the resources are created with Terraform.

`launch_template.tf`;

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "launch-template" {
  name                   = var.name
  update_default_version = var.update_default_version

  instance_type = var.instance_type

  key_name = var.key_name

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = var.block_device_name

    ebs {
      volume_size = var.volume_size
    }
  }

  ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized

  monitoring {
    enabled = var.monitoring_enabled
  }

  dynamic "tag_specifications" {
    for_each = toset(var.resources_to_tag)
    content {
       resource_type = tag_specifications.key
       tags = var.tags
    }
  }
}
```

`eks_nodegroup.tf`;

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-nodegroup" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  node_group_name = var.node_group_name
  node_role_arn  = var.node_role_arn
  subnet_ids     = var.subnet_ids

  labels = var.labels

  tags = var.tags

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.desired_size
    max_size     = var.max_size
    min_size     = var.min_size
  }

  launch_template {
    id        = var.launch_template_id
    version   = var.launch_template_version
  }
}
```

These resources are binding each other. But at the end of the day,
this setup is creating

- 2 launch templates,
- 1 autoscaling group
- 2 volumes for each instance in autoscaling group.

I understood from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576026/unexpected-behaviour-of-aws-asg-aws-launch-template-within-aws-eks) that, because I'm using `aws_launch_template` resource with `aws_eks_node_group`; second launch template is being created. But I didn't understand where the second volume is coming from for each instance. One of the volumes fits my configuration which has `40 GB` capacity, path is `/dev/sda1` and `IOPS` is 120. But the second one has `20 GB` capacity, path is `/dev/xvda` and `IOPS` is 100. I don't have any configuration like this in my Terraform structure.

I didn't find where is the source of the second volume. Any guidance will be highly appreciated, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `disk_size` parameter is not configurable when using a launch template. It will cause an error if configured.

I suspect you may be using a Bottlerocket AMI which comes with two volumes. One is the OS volume and the second is the data volume. You likely want to configure the data volume size which is exposed at `/dev/xvdb` by default.

See https://github.com/bottlerocket-os/bottlerocket#default-volumes

Comment: Correct answer. Bottlerocket uses 2Gi for OS and 20 Gi for data.

Answer (score 0):

Your second volume is being created based on the default volume for the [`aws_eks_node_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#disk_size). The `disk_size` parameter is set by default to 20 GB.